# Why am I getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grading' in Jupyiter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Trying to do a corsera assignment I am now running the .ipynb file in my local jupyiter notebook I am getting this error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grading'**[image]

Comment: `grading` is probably a python file provided by Coursera. You might need to download it separately.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on coursera log on top left you can see the notebook files of your course. This file is on the root.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error, although the solution is pretty easy, you just have to read the README at all:

https://github.com/hse-aml/intro-to-dl#prepare-resources-inside-jupyter-notebooks-for-local-setups-only

In summary:

**Clone the repository**

`git clone https://github.com/hse-aml/intro-to-dl.git`

And now open the task via you jupiter instance (you have to navigate into the root of the repo first).
Then open the task:
E.g.

`/intro-to-dl/week3/week3_task1_first_cnn_cifar10_clean.ipynb`

In order to make this post full in solution there is one more mandatory and one more optional step.

**Download datasets**

Before you could proceed with the tasks, you have to initialize the datasets. For this open and run:

`/intro-to-dl/download_resources.ipynb`

**Open Docker container's bash (only in case of docker)**

`docker exec -it {name or id of your jupiter container} /bin/bash`

And execute the **git clone** here. So you containerized instance will "see" the repo.

Now you can proceed with the tasks.

P.S.: I was not able to execute commands (like git) via jupiter, I have no option for that on the client, this is why that `docker` command is added.

Comment: During the answer I assumed @theUturn you were asking about the same course: https://github.com/hse-aml/intro-to-dl
If no, them let me know and I will modify the answer for a more general one.